# unable to decide whether kafka JdbcSourceConnector.java is writing data to topic or not

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

This is for my personal research
Aim:Stream data from a table to a Kafka topic and then consume that data from Kafka topic to write to a file.

API used: I'm currently trying to use Kafka Connectors, JdbcSourceConnector class to be precise.

**Constraint: Use Confluent Java API and not do it through CLI or by executing provided shell script.**

What I did: create an instance of JdbcSourceConnector.java class and call start(Properties) method of this class by providing the Properties object as a parameter. This properties object has database connection properties, table whitelist property, topic prefix etc.

**Questions:**

1. After starting thread, i'm unable to read the data from "topic-prefix-tablename" topic. Just calling start() method enough to put data to topic or should I also instantiate JdbCSourceTask class?
2. After putting data into topic using JdbcSourceConnector class, can we consume data using normal Kafka consumer or we need to write a JdbcSinkConnector class?
3. Is there a simple java API tutorial page/example code i can refer because all the examples i see are using CLI/shell scripts?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: SO is not a place you come and ask someone to do your homework. You post a problem, give the code for what you have tried so far. And then people try to pitch in. No one is sitting here to do your homework.

Comment: *or we need to write a JdbcSinkConnector class?* - Well, no part of your question wanted to write to a database, so that's not necessary. Regarding point 3 - the entire Kafka Connect API is open source, that's your example code. Asking for tutorials is off topic for Stackoverflow

Comment: @AbhisekRoy dont assume that this is a homework and I’m asking for any your favour. When you don’t know you should either help the person or keep quite. Whatever i tried is very little and I’m going to post that.

Comment: @cricket_007 _itallic_Well, no part of your question wanted to write to a database, so that's not necessary_itallic_ - I thought we need to use JdbcSinkConnector class just to read from the topic. I will try and have a look at the examples given in the source code.

Comment: "Sink to" external system to Kafka. "Source from" external system to Kafka. That's the terminology

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to use the Java API directly? The JDBC Source connector and FileStream Sink connector implement the Kafka Connect API and do exactly what you want to do for you. This is illustrated with examples in [this article here](https://www.confluent.io/blog/simplest-useful-kafka-connect-data-pipeline-world-thereabouts-part-1/).

If you want to transform the data you would then use Kafka Streams or KSQL to consume the topic being written to and apply the required transformations. You can also look at [Single Message Transform](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#connect_transforms) if you want to do simple transformations within Kafka Connect workflow itself.

So you'd have :

```
[database] --- Kafka Connect 
                JDBC source   --> [ Kafka topic A ]
                                         |
                                         |
                                    Kafka Streams 
                                       or KSQL
                                         |
                                         |
                                         V
                                  [ Kafka topic B] -- Kafka Connect --> [ /tmp/foo ]
                                                       File Sink
```

Comment: My idea is to use JdbcSourceConnector class from Confluent Kafka API. When the data is streamed from Table to topic, after reading it from topic, i would like to perform certain transformation logic (minor data changes) and write it to a file.      P.S: You probably missed adding the link in your answer. Please add it, so that I can go ahead and take a look. Thanks for answering the question!

Comment: Link added, sorry about that, and answer amended to address your comment

Comment: Thank you for the link. But i want to implement the same in Java code i.e. I added the Confluent-kafka maven dependency, then in a simple Java class main() method created an instance of JdbcSourceConnector.java class and called start() method on that instance object. I'm really new to Kafka world and not really sure what i'm doing here.

Comment: Why? Why are you wanting to write in Java what is done already for you and just need configuration files to implement?

Comment: My constraint is that, I don't have access to the system where Confluent Kafka connect is installed. All I have is a windows machine with Confluent Kafka jar files which i can use in a Java project. I don't want to rewrite JdbcSourceConnector again in Java. I want to use inbuilt Confluent connectors to write data to a topic using Java. Please help.

Comment: So is this an artificial constraint, for the purposes of homework/learning? Or you're being asked to build/deploy an application in these constraints?

Comment: This is not an homework or learning. I’m working on a POC to check the feasibility of creating a stream of data from database and integrate it with our existing systems. And yes it is to deploy an application in these constraints.

Comment: The pattern I've given you is the right way to do this. You can run Kafka Connect within a docker container; there is no reason for this constraint of not using it. To try and write your own Java code makes no sense at all based on what you've told me. If you want to drive along a road you get in a car, you don't decide to build the car from scratch before driving it :)